# What is the equivalent for the ActiveMQ 5.x sendFailIfNoSpace setting in Artemis?

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I'm working with a Spring Boot app that uses Spring's `JmsTemplate` to send messages to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue. If the disk space is full and the queue is blocking then any `JmsTemplate` calls to `convertAndSend` will hang forever. It would be better for me for it to give an error instead.

ActiveMQ has a configuration for this, i.e. `sendFailIfNoSpace`:

```xml
<systemUsage>
    <systemUsage sendFailIfNoSpace="true">
        <memoryUsage>
            <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
        </memoryUsage>
    </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

Is there a way to configure an Artemis queue to do this as well?

Some of the specifics in the application are:

A Spring auto configured `JmsTemplate` call:

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("just another message");
```

The Artemis broker has the default settings for any queue involved:

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
   <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
   <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
   <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
   <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
   <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
   <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
   <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
   <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
   <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
   <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
   <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
</address-setting>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no equivalent to `sendFailIfNoSpace` in ActiveMQ Artemis. As noted in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#max-disk-usage), the broker will block when the `max-disk-usage` is exceeded:

> The System will perform scans on the disk to determine if the disk is beyond a configured limit. These are configured through `max-disk-usage` in percentage. Once that limit is reached any message will be blocked. (unless the protocol doesn't support flow control on which case there will be an exception thrown and the connection for those clients dropped).

To be clear, the client calls won't be blocked *forever*. They will just be blocked until sufficient space on the disk is freed.